# Unable to update ' and "" in the stop_word list

Tags: nlp, nltk, stop-words

> I tried to update ' and " in my stop_word list.

```
> stop_words.update(["'","""])
> stop_words
```

I got the following error.

```
    > File "<ipython-input-85-54a2b8b08201>", line 2
    > stop_words
    > 
    > 
    > SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal--
```

How to update those characters in the stop_word ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal `"` can e.g. be denoted as `'"'` or `"\""`. Your `"""` syntactically starts a [triple-quoted string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (which is never ended, causing the `SyntaxError`).